# Partitioning of a Stream

Tags: scala

I'm not sure if this is possible but I want to partition a stream based on some condition that depends on the output of the stream. It will make sense with an example I think.

I will create a bunch of orders which I will stream since the actual use case is a stream of orders coming in so it is not known up front what the next order will be or even the full list of orders:

```
scala> case class Order(item : String, qty : Int, price : Double)
defined class Order

scala> val orders = List(Order("bike", 1, 23.34), Order("book", 3, 2.34), Order("lamp", 1, 9.44), Order("bike", 1, 23.34))
orders: List[Order] = List(Order(bike,1,23.34), Order(book,3,2.34), Order(lamp,1,9.44), Order(bike,1,23.34))
```

Now I want to partition/group these orders into one set which contain duplicate orders and another set which contains unique orders. So in the above example, when I force the stream it should create two streams: one with the two orders for a bike (Since they are the same) and another stream containing all the other orders.

I tried the following:

created the partitioning function:

```
scala> def matchOrders(o : Order, s : Stream[Order]) = s.contains(o)
matchOrders: (o: Order, s: Stream[Order])Boolean
```

then tried to apply this to stream:

```
scala> val s : (Stream[Order], Stream[Order]) = orders.toStream.partition(matchOrders(_, s._1))
```

I got a null pointer exception since I guess the `s._1` is empty initially?? I'm not sure. I've tried other ways but I'm not getting very far. Is there a way to achieve this partitioning?

Answer (score 2):

That would not work anyway, because the first duplicate `Order` would have already gone to the unique `Stream` when you would process its duplicate.

The best way is to create a `Map[Order, Boolean]` which tells you if an `Order` appears more than once in the original orders list.

```
val matchOrders = orders.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size > 1)
val s : (Stream[Order], Stream[Order]) = orders.toStream.partition(matchOrders(_))
```

Comment: As I explained, it is not known up front what the whole order list is so you can't write your matchOrders predicate like you have. I created the above order list just to give an example. But you did make a good point about the first order; I thought about that as well. I think I may to need to create some sort of recursive stream structure; I'm experimenting with that at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can only know that an order has no duplicates after your stream finishes. So since the standard `Stream` constructors require you to know whether the stream is empty, it seems they aren't lazy enough: you have to force your original stream to even begin building the no-duplicates stream. And of course if you do this, Helder Pereira's answer applies.